# Does tty7 have bash running?

Tags: bash, xorg, tty

tty7 have the `Xorg` server running in Ubuntu. I wanted to know if tty7 also have `bash` running (my assumption was that `bash` first runs on tty7, and then `bash` executes `Xorg`).

I have listed all of the processes on the system to see how many `bash` processes are running:

[image]

The `bash` process shown in the image is the `bash` process that belongs to the terminal I am running, so this means that tty7 does not have a `bash` process running.

Am I correct, or is there some reason that prevents the `bash` process that belongs to tty7 to appear in the processes listing?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text; just copy/paste it into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for a bash process to be running there. The display manager, LightDM or GDM or something else, *may* use a shell to start the user session (LightDM does, GDM, doesn't), but they don't need to run bash to start Xorg. Not everything is a script.

Answer (score 0):

As bash is an interactive shell process, or used to run scripts, it is not necessary for things which do not fit into that category. Just as there aren't special bash processes for apache, mysql, or other system services, there aren't such special processes for general user services either.

A shell only needs to be run if the user is logging in to a terminal (either by tty, serial console, ssh, GUI terminal emulator, or otherwise), or to run a script for which the shell is the interpreter.

Also, bash is simply the default login shell for users. Some may choose to change this to csh, zsh, or some other shell, as well.